# Very stumped on nested void functions with nexted for / if statements

Tags: c++

Ok, I've simplified my problem greatly and it is almost perfect except 1 small nagging problem. The function I couldn't figure out how to work I simply turned into its own cpp file for now.

I cannot for the life of me understand why this thing is running smooth the first time, but every time after that it takes in 2 lines to work..

```
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>
#include <locale>         // std::locale, std::isdigit, std::isalpha
#include <sstream>        // std::stringstream
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <limits>

void check_row (int row);                  // Passes int row (row size) from main
void check_set (int row);

int continue_while_int = 0;
int P_row_value;


int main()
{
    int row;
    std::cout<<"Enter an int row ";
    std::cin >> row;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    while (continue_while_int == 0)
    {
       check_set(row);
    }
}

void check_set(int row)
{
    check_row(row);
}

void check_row (int row) // 1. clear and ignore incase incorrect input is given. 2. Input string. Checks if empty, "exit" or "Exit", valid length, if input
{
        int row_copy = row;

        std::string row_length_string;
        std::string input_length_string;

        std::stringstream convert_row;                                    // stringstream used for the conversion
        convert_row << row_copy;                                          //add the value of Number to the characters in the stream
        row_length_string = convert_row.str();                            //set Result to the content of the stream

        std::string input_Row;
        std::cout << "enter the P_row ";
        for (int i = 0; std::cin.clear(),std::cin.ignore(10000,'\n') ; i++)     // clears error flags, ignores all input after enter.
        {
            std::getline(std::cin, input_Row);


//            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            std::string ifempty = input_Row;
            std::string input_Row_copy = input_Row;                      // creates copy of input
            std::stringstream ss_convert_input(input_Row_copy);          // gives copy to stringstream instance

            int input_length = input_Row_copy.length();                  // sets an int as input's length                                                     // length of input
            int row_length = row_length_string.length();                 // sets and int as length of row

            int input_as_int;                                            // int to hold input if valid numb string

            if(ifempty.length() == 0)
            {
                std::cout << "error : nothing entered " << std::endl;
            }
            else if (input_Row_copy == "exit" || input_Row_copy == "Exit")
            {
                std::cout << "Exiting ";
                continue_while_int = 1;                                                                             // Exit check_set loop
                break;
            }
            else if (input_length != row_length)                                                                    // if larger than row_length digits or less than or equal to 0 digits
            {
                std::cout << "error : "<< input_Row_copy;
                std::cout << " is outside row input length "<< std::endl << std::endl;                               // restar
            }
            else if(!(ss_convert_input >> input_as_int))                                                              // restart if unable to convert
            {
                std::cout << "error : invalid entry of " << input_Row << std::endl<< std::endl;
            }
            else if (input_length == row_length)
            {
                if (input_as_int < row && input_as_int >= 0)
                {
                    P_row_value = input_as_int;
                    std::cout << "Successfully converted string to int. P_row_value = [" << P_row_value << "]" <<"[Column]";
                    std::cout.width(20);
                    std::cout << " && Input length is " << input_length << std::endl << std::endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout << "error : " << input_Row_copy << " is not within row boundaries" << std::endl;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << " error: unknown exception : " << input_Row << std::endl << std::endl;
            }
            convert_row.str(std::string() );
            convert_row.clear();
//          std::cin.ignore(std::cin.rdbuf()->in_avail(),'\n');
    }
}
```

The output

Enter an int row 4

enter the P_row 3
Successfully converted string to int. P_row_value = [3][Column] && Input length is 1

2
2
Successfully converted string to int. P_row_value = [2][Column] && Input length is 1

3
3
Successfully converted string to int. P_row_value = [3][Column] && Input length is 1

1
1
Successfully converted string to int. P_row_value = [1][Column] && Input length is 1

e
e
error : invalid entry of e

r
r
error : invalid entry of r

error : nothing entered

Comment: You need to show a lot more code than you have. This code has no user input and we have no idea about `check_set` or any of the other functions you described.

Comment: check_set is within the pastebin and the input of the other functions are ints for an array. 

The user is supposed to input strings that correspond to the array that's already been made. The reason for a string and not an int is because it will check if the string entered is exit or Exit or if it's an empty space.

Comment: @user3469603 avoid pasting external links for code, instead paste it here on SOF with a correct format

Comment: I just uploaded it to pastebin because there was a ton of code